# How to translate this image processing from Matlab to OpenCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, opencv3.0

The link below use Matlab to remove non-text content from an image. I want to do the same thing with OpenCV in Java.

I don't have a Matlab to try with and I am new to OpenCV. Though I know some basics about the theory behind the process, but it's kind of difficult to make the translation from Matlab language into OpenCV 3.0. And preferably in Java.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html

### ADD 1 - region detection with MSER  (not resolved yet)

For MSER detection, I can use the following code to detect the MSER keypoints.

```
public static void MSERdetector(String imgName1, String suffix1) {
    Mat imgMat1 = Imgcodecs.imread(picDir + imgName1 + "." + suffix1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    String outImgName1 = picDir + "MSER" + "_keypoints_" + imgName1 + "_"   + ".tif";
    Mat outImg1 = new Mat();        

FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER); // create the feature detector

MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
featureDetector.detect(imgMat1, keypoints1);

if (!keypoints1.empty()) {
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(imgMat1, keypoints1, outImg1);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(outImgName1, outImg1);
    System.out.println("done");
}
else {
    System.out.println("No keypoints found for: " + imgName1);
}
```

}

And the output looks like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to convert keypoints into regions. What I need is below:

[image]

### ADD 2 - Canny edges and intersection with MSER regions (not resolved yet)

Once I am able to find the MSER regions, I am supposed to `intersect it with Canny edges`. I can find some Canny edges as below. But I don't know how to do the `intersection` operation.

```
public static void CANNYedge(String imgName1, String suffix1) {
    Mat imgMat1 = Imgcodecs.imread(picDir + imgName1 + "." + suffix1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    //imgMat1 = ImageUtilities.Convert2BW(imgMat1);
    String outImgName1 = picDir + "_CANNY_" + imgName1 + ".tif";
    Mat outImg1 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(imgMat1, outImg1, 0, 500);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(outImgName1, outImg1);
}
```

My canny edges output looks like this:
[image]

### ADD 3 - Now I turned to use VS 2013 Community

For setting up OpenCV with VS2013, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541899/unresolved-external-symbol-error-when-linking-with-opencv-3-0).

### ADD 4 - Coding in VC++ 2013

Below is what I tried for now with reference to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515084/opencv-3-0-0-mser-binary-mask).

```
//Step2: Detect MSER regions
Mat grayImage;
cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
imshow("Gray Image", grayImage);
waitKey(0);


Ptr<MSER> mserExtractor = MSER::create(); // create MSER extractor with default parameters. http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/MSER http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d28/classcv_1_1MSER.html#a49d72a1346413106516a7fc6d95c09bb
mserExtractor->setMinArea(150);
mserExtractor->setMaxArea(2000);
//Mat mserOutMask = Mat::zeros(grayImage.rows, grayImage.cols, CV_8UC3);

Mat vis;
//vis = Mat::zeros(grayImage.rows, grayImage.cols, CV_8UC3);
grayImage.copyTo(vis);

vector<vector<Point>> mserContours;
vector<Rect> mserBBox;//what's this?
mserExtractor->detectRegions(grayImage, mserContours, mserBBox);

for (int i = 0; i<mserContours.size(); i++)
{
    drawContours(vis, mserContours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 4);
}

imshow("MSER by contours", vis);
waitKey(0);

Mat vis2;
grayImage.copyTo(vis2);
for (vector<cv::Point> v : mserContours){
    for (cv::Point p : v){
        vis2.at<uchar>(p.y, p.x) = 255;
    }
}
imshow("MSER by points", vis);
waitKey(0);
```

What I got are these:

`vis1 - MSER by contours`
[image]

`vis2 - MSER by points`
[image]

### ADD 5

I just experimented with the [text detection sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp) as suggested by `Miki`.
It requires some trained model files to run. And it took almost 2 minutes to finish but we can leave the performance later. **My scenario is to OCR texts from complex screenshots** (sorry to reveal that until now). Though the result is quite good for natural scenes. It is not so appealing for screenshots. Below is the result:

[image]

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31377228/5008845) for a starting point

Comment: @Miki Thanks for the link. I am not looking for a detailed code writing. But for a clue of the mapping between the 2 new realms to me. Please don't mis-interpret it.

Comment: I am wondering if the Java wrapper is complete for OpenCV 3.0. Do I `have to` use C++?

Comment: You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515084/opencv-3-0-0-mser-binary-mask) to draw MSER regions. I don't know about Java, if you're ok with C++ I could probably help you...

Comment: you can get instrsection by [ANDing](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) the two images

Comment: @Miki I have turned to use VC++, and some linking errors arose. Please see my ADD 3. Thx.

Comment: It seems you are not linking the required libs. Did you linked opencv_coreXXX, opencv_imgprocXXX etc?

Comment: @Miki I have turned to use VC++ 2013. Appreciate if you can provide some code sample.

Comment: Did you see OpenCV [Scene Text Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html) and this [example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp)?

Comment: Don't know that until now. Will take a look. Thx.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971599/5008845) could be useful. See also the paper linked in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer just to show the result of the OpenCV [text detection example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp)

[image]

Now you need to apply text recognition, using for example [OCRHMMDecoder](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/ocr.html)

You'll find a sample [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/webcam_demo.cpp)