# OpenCV error: “LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core300d.lib' ”

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

I'm trying to compile a simple code in visual studio + opencv, but got this error.

Code:

```
#include <cstdio.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

void main(){  
   std::cout<<CV_VERSION;
}
```

Output:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_core300d.lib'
error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited code1104.
```

Comment: You are not linking opencv_core... Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845) and follow the steps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably added the correct include directories, but you forgot to link the actual libraries.

Under `Configuration Properties` - `Linker` - `General` - `Additional Library Directories` you need to add the following:
`$(OPENCV_DIR)\staticlib;`

With `OPENCV_DIR` pointing to your build folder.
For example: `E:\opencv\build\x86\vc12`.

After you've done that, you also need to add the lines below here under `Configuration Properties` - `Linker` - `Input` - `Additional Dependencies`

```
IlmImfd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libpngd.lib
libjpegd.lib
libtiffd.lib
libwebpd.lib
opencv_calib3d300d.lib
opencv_core300d.lib
opencv_features2d300d.lib
opencv_flann300d.lib
opencv_hal300d.lib
opencv_highgui300d.lib
opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib
opencv_imgproc300d.lib
opencv_ml300d.lib
opencv_objdetect300d.lib
opencv_photo300d.lib
opencv_shape300d.lib
opencv_stitching300d.lib
opencv_superres300d.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
opencv_video300d.lib
opencv_videoio300d.lib
opencv_videostab300d.lib
zlibd.lib
ippicvmt.lib
comctl32.lib
vfw32.lib
```

You only need to add the ones you need, but there's no negative side at adding them all. Then, you're sure you didn't forget anything.

Comment: There is no folder called `staticlib`. Additionally, there is no `vc12` but `vc14` (under x64). So this answer is not really helping.

Answer (score 2):

In opencv (vc14 and vc15) its enough to put opencv_world420d.lib (in debug) and opencv_world420.lib (in release). Most probably somewhere in the code there are leftovers from previous versions. This opencv_core300d.lib is included core libraries which is already inside opencv_world420d.lib.