# Missing opencv_world300.lib while using visual studio 2015/2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.0.0 to my project within MS Visual Studio 2013/2015 (two PCs). I'm doing same things as in tutorial described here http://tinyurl.com/cbdvucw, but on both PCs I get an error, saying that 'opencv_world300.lib is missing, try to reinstall programm'. I sure that it's not missing, I've set system variables: OPENCV_DIR: 'D:\opencv\build\x86\vc12' and added to PATH: '%OPENCV_DIR%\lib'. Restarted my computer, but Visual Studio says error above. All project properties are the same as in the tutorial. What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845)

Answer (score -2):

You need to build the library again 
Go back to cmake step and activate Build_opencv_world

[image]