# Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, computer-vision

I keep getting this error "Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core.hpp': No such file or directory". I am using Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 3.0 and opencv2/core.hpp is in OpenCV 3 so I'm not sure what the problem is. I have set up the additional include directories in the debug property pages. Any idea what my problem is?

> C/C++-> General -> Additional include dependencies -> C:/opencv/build;
>   C:/opencv/build/include; C:/opencv/build/include/opencv;
>   C:/opencv/modules/core/include; C:/opencv/modules/imgproc/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/flann/include; C:/opencv/modules/highgui/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/features2d/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/calib3d/include; C:/opencv/modules/ml/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/video/include; C:/opencv/modules/objdetect/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/contrib/include; C:/opencv/modules/nonfree/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/photo/include; C:/opencv/modules/legacy/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/gpu/include; C:/opencv/modules/stitching/include;
>   C:/opencv/modules/ts/include; C:/opencv/modules/videostab/include;
>   %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
>
> Linker -> general -> additional library directories ->
>   $(OPENCV_DIR)\x86\vc11\staticlib
>
> Linker -> Input -> opencv_calib3d300d.lib; opencv_core300d.lib;
>   opencv_features2d300d.lib; opencv_flann300d.lib; opencv_hal300d.lib;
>   opencv_highgui300d.lib; opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib;
>   opencv_imgproc300d.lib; opencv_ml300d.lib; opencv_objdetect300d.lib;
>   opencv_photo300d.lib; opencv_shape300d.lib; opencv_stitching300d.lib;
>   opencv_superres300d.lib; opencv_ts300d.lib; opencv_video300d.lib;
>   opencv_videoio300d.lib; opencv_videostab300d.lib; libtiffd.lib;
>   libpngd.lib; libjpegd.lib; libjasperd.lib; IlmImfd.lib; libwebpd.lib;
>   ippicvmt.lib; zlibd.lib; comctl32.lib; vfw32.lib;
>   %(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: show include and library directory, and additional libraries

Comment: I've updated the question now

Comment: additional include should be just `C:/opencv/build/include; `

Comment: I changed it to that and I am still getting the error

Comment: have you deleted all others include paths?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm really confused because i haven't had this problem before

Comment: are you including it in your code as: `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`?

Comment: I have it as  '#include "opencv2/core.hpp"' I changed it to '#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>' and it is still not working

Comment: delete all other includes related to OpenCV, except opencv.hpp, and let me know.

Comment: i actually don't have that line in my code

Comment: well.. try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845). Remember to correct vc12 to vc11... Good luck

Comment: Could you post the code you typed during #include..
that is the #include statement #include "Directory\opencv2\core\core.hpp"

Comment: “debug property pages” — Are you doing a release build by chance?

Answer (score -1):

the "C/C++-> General -> Additional include dependencies" config error.
You should add the following entry:
"C:/opencv/build/include;C:/opencv/build/include/opencv;C:/opencv/build/include/opencv/opencv2;"