# How to resolve an error: imread is not a member of cv?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, imread

I use OpenCV 3.0 and Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm trying to compile a few codes on Ubuntu using OpenCV. I get error

> "error: 'imread' is not a member of 'cv'"

Due to my previous search knowledge, I tried compiling by adding "highgui.h".

I use:

```
$g++ main.cpp HOG.cpp HOGFeaturesOfBlock.cpp -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lml -lcvaux -highgui -lcv -lcxcore -o featureExtractor
```

on the terminal to compile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] so we can see exactly what you've done - otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: You have not set OpenCV correctly. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845) to know what to include and link (here are added to a Visual Studio project, just add to you gcc command line).

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to extract features form depth images in main.cpp I have also readData.cpp which is invoked in main. cpp in which I used imread when I tried to compile I get readData.cpp:error: 'imread' is not a member of 'cv'

Comment: @Miki I use Ubuntu, not Windows :/

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But you need to include and link opencv properly.

Comment: in opencv3 afaik imread isnt part of highgui anymore. try to find the right module or include the all-in-one-header, opencv.hpp or similar

Comment: Check out [here](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) @berriel did a nice tutorial.

Comment: Just add this header file  #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

Answer (score 9):

The following commands should work. If it doesn't work you should check if you set the include/lib files correctly.

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv\cv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

Mat image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Comment: 1) you don't need `#include <opencv\cv.hpp>`, 2) you can just use `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` 3) without a `main` this won't work, 4) Opencv 3.0 parameter is now called `IMREAD_COLOR`

Comment: I included those headers to my code, but this time I get another error, /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lml and same error for other libraries

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
```

solved the problem which contains the imread function

Answer (score 0):

I found that the compile command had to be very specific (besides having added `using namespace cv;` in the code), with the source file having to come directly after the `g++`, as follows;

```
g++ test.cpp -fpermissive $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) -o testbin
```

Replace `opencv` with `opencv4` if that is what you use

Answer (score -1):

I had a same question before. 
Just add `#include "imgcodec.hpp"`, 
Hope this can help you