# Cannot open source file "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to run this code that should open the webcam and take frames.
However, I am getting this error. `Cannot open source file "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"`

[image]

I download opencv and VS15, I followed online guides on how to install opencv 3.1 on VS15 using CMAKE.

However, It gives the error I mentioned above along side some more errors

```
Cannot open source file "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

Cannot open source file "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

I am really new to this and it got me frustrated. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the _include_ directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Visual Studio look for C++ Header files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files)

Comment: How do I add the include directory ?
I added in linker the opencv2 include path. I am not sure If I did it properly.

Comment: check step 7 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845)

Comment: Could you post the code instead of a screenshot ? (even if the problem may just be the include search path)

Answer (score 0):

I copied the files into the project folder and just included the file names rather than the filepath, then I used tools -> NuGet package manager -> NuGet Package Console and entered 
PM > Install-Package opencvdefault

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenCV on Windows, VS, I think you had better download `opencv.exe` and extract and compile automatically.

Add this dll and header file to the VS path. And add opencv path to the system environment, then restart Windows