# How to get ALL the text from a screen display?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, ocr, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I have been struggling to get `ALL` the text from a screen display. My application tries to do some automation such as:

- Wait for some text to show up or vanish in the screen display.
- Move mouse to some text.

So I need to find all the texts in screen, and locate them.

I have tried to use OCR technology with the screenshot ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519808/how-to-translate-this-image-processing-from-matlab-to-opencv)). But the result is depressing. Now I turned to the [Windows UI automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684007(v=vs.85).aspx) technology. I am willing to learn COM and anything necessary. I believe it can detect text such as window title, button text, etc. But I deeply doubt that it can do the following things:

- Detect text from the content area of a control, such as text displayed in notepad.
- Detect text displayed in the console window.

Anyone have done such thing before? Any other options?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can read text from other applications, but it ultimately depends on the application. notepad for example works fine with UIA: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samathew/archive/2009/11/03/automation-with-windows-ui-automation.aspx this is not the case with Console apps that don't work. For those, you'll have to use other ways. Last note: to read everything possible (whatever the technology is), you will have to be an administrator on the box.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the hint.